# ECONNRESET error while insert data to bigquery

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I getting ECONNRESET error when trying to insert data( as stream) into BigQuery using google-cloud node module.

```
var writeToBigQuery = function(message,t){


    var table = dataset.table(t);

    var options ={ "ignoreUnknownValues":true}

    table.insert(message,options,insertHandler);


}

var insertHandler = function(err, insertErrors, apiResponse) {


    //api error?
    if(err){
        //notify
        console.log("fail to write data: "+ JSON.stringify(err))
        return;
    }

    //insert error?
    if(insertErrors.length > 0){
        //notify
        console.log("fail to write data: "+ JSON.stringify(insertErrors))
        return;
    }

    //row saved successfully!
}
```

I am trying to write a file with some jsons. I know that I can use bigquery job but I need to modify some json's values before write it to bigquery.

Can it be my local connection problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any chance you got a resolution?